# Why can't I do a git push from my repository?

Tags: git, github

I recently cloned a git repository from a different user account I have on GitHub as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/some_user/fav-front.git
```

and am getting:

```
remote: Permission to user_current/fav-front.git denied to user_prev.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_current/fav-front.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

However I can still do a git push using my **current user**.

**Reference**

https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository

https://help.github.com/en/articles/create-a-repo

**Update**

This seems to be an authentication issue.  I noticed none of my user information is populate when I do `git config --list` in my repos.

I tried setting my user name and email manually but even this did not work:

> ~/_top/fav-front> git config user.email 'foo@foo.com'
>
> ~/_top/fav-front> git config user.name 'foo'

Comment: How did you authenticate the `git clone` operation?

Comment: How do you normally authenticate a `git push` in your other repo?

Comment: Check the output from `git remote -v` in both repos. This will show whether you are using ssh or https.

Comment: Since cloning is a read-only operation, authentication isn't  required. It should not affect any authentication on other repos or accounts.

Comment: Sorry.  I updated my question.  Git seems to think I am a different user.  Don't know how to troubleshoot as `git config --list` returns nothing.

Comment: Note that git doesn't natively support authentication. It relies on 3rd-party tools, such as an ssh client or keychain, to do so. The `user.name` and `user.email` in the config are used to tag commits but not for any authentication.

Comment: Is the repository private?

Answer (score 0):

`user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with authentication.
Only Git commit authorship.

Do check the `git config credential.helper` output: if, for instance, `osxkeychain`, as in [Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git), then [check the keychain as in here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain), for the github.com entry:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/setup/keychain-entry.png]

Edit or delete the entry accordingly.